# проблема с telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Есть код:

```py
    import json
    from requests import get
    import telebot

    json_ = json.loads(get("http://ipinfo.io/json").text)
    print(json_["ip"])


    token = ''
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['give_info'])
    def info(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{json_}")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        bot.polling()
```

Когда мы принтуем, то получаем стандартный ip...
Но когда мы пишем функцию боту, то нам пишет

> <function bot..info at 0x000001B8E1724430>

Comment: если бот должен отправить ip, то следует из `json_` и в сообщении отдавать ip: `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{json_["ip"]}")`

Comment: Похоже, вы нам не весь код привели, т.к. этот код не может дать такого результата, в этом коде json_ - очевидно не функция. Скорее всего, в той части кода, который вы не стали приводить, где-то в переменную json_ записывается некая функция.